# Importing associations, dependencies etc. from PHP code in Enterprise architect

Tags: php, enterprise-architect

I have imported some php classes from code into a diagram. Extensions and realizations are created automatically. 
Is there anyway of making it show automatically associations, dependencies, realisations, ect?

Answer (score 0):

EA will create some, but not all associations between classes. It has a limited compiler for all languages it supports. You can however, add them manually in the created class model.